# How to detect SIM card in android 3.0?

Tags: android

I am new to use of android 3.0 or we can say android tablet. I want to know how we can detect a SIM card in tablet/android 3.0? Can anyone give me the example code.

EDIT:- 
    My requirement is when some condition is match then I want to unmout SIM card. I mean user is not able to use the service of SIM card. Can we do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try to read SIM information from your application. if it returns values then Your tablet has SIM card otherwise it will return NULL. for e.g. try to read IMSI number, if your application able to read it that means your tablet has SIM card, otherwise there is no SIM, if application returns NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Use the TelephonyManager service and his method getSimState().
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#SIM_STATE_ABSENT

if there is no Sim card it'll return `SIM_STATE_ABSENT`

François

Comment: Thanks for your reply I edit my question. Can you please tell me the answer of that?

Comment: I think it's not possible to do that! Look at the following links : http://source.android.com/tech/security/index.html#sim-card-access